# OSX Change default program to brew installed binary

Tags: macos, pdf, homebrew, evince

I'm very disappointed that Apple was still not capable to fix Preview app and my PDFs are all still *blurry* ([comparison between Evince and Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEp4Q.png)) on FullHD monitors. So I installed Evince from brew and when I want to use it, I must always use terminal and type `nohup evince` (or something similar...).

So my question is: **How can I configure for example `/usr/local/Cellar/evince/3.26.0_2/bin/evince` as my default PDF viewer?**

I tried to create `.command` script or `.app` file with Evince binary in it but it just not working when i try to set it up as default program for anything. :/

*OSX version: 10.13.3

Hardware: MacBook Pro 13" 2015 Early*

Comment: wow still seems theres no solid answer for reading params of the default app

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using fink?

http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/evince

It is similar to homebrew, it has lots of GNU packages, however I am not near a MacOS system right now and I cannot tell you if it will create an actual app icon for you.